# PyOpenGL cannot compile shader

Tags: opengl, python-3.x, pyqt, shader

I'm using Python3, Qt4 and PyOpenGL on Debian testing with the python3-pyside packages. This the minimized example code:

```
#!/bin/env python3

from OpenGL.GL import shaders, GL_VERTEX_SHADER
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget

class MyGLWidget(QGLWidget):
    def initializeGL(self):
        self.vertex_shader = shaders.compileShader("""
        #version 330
        layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = position;
        }
        """, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(["shader fail"])
    widget = MyGLWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This is the error:

```
$ python3 fail.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fail.py", line 16, in initializeGL
    """, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.py", line 231, in compileShader
    shaderType,
RuntimeError: ("Shader compile failure (0): b'0:1(13): preprocessor error: syntax error, unexpected HASH_TOKEN\\n'", [b'\n        #version 330\n        layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n        void main()\n        {\n            gl_Position = position;\n        }\n        '], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
```

This is the most simple shader I can think of and the error is not very descriptive. Can you please help me?

EDIT:
If in `initializeGL` I first do `print(self.context().format())`, the output is

```
<PySide.QtOpenGL.QGLFormat(options QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x4|0x8|0x20|0x80|0x400) , plane  0 , depthBufferSize  24 , accumBufferSize  -1 , stencilBufferSize  8 , redBufferSize  8 , greenBufferSize  8 , blueBufferSize  8 , alphaBufferSize  8 , samples  -1 , swapInterval  0 , majorVersion  1 , minorVersion  0 , profile  0 )   at 0x7f66bc804508>
```

Which means I get an OpenGL 1.0 context. So I guess I have to request a higher version context somehow.

As for my graphics hardware: I use the integrated graphics in my Intel i7-4710MQ with the Debian default driver. It identifies to lspci as

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

More interestingly:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.4.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.4.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.4.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.0
```

So the hardware+driver should be able to do the trick.

Update:

```
print(int(QGLFormat.openGLVersionFlags()))
```

gives `4223` which includes versions up to 3.0 but not 3.1 or higher, which is weird because up to 3.3 should be available.

If I try requesting a higher version context like this:

```
fmt = QGLFormat(QGLFormat.OpenGL_Version_3_3 | QGLFormat.CompatibilityProfile)
widget = MyGLWidget(fmt)
```

or try it with `Version_3_0` or `Version_2_0` with `QGLFormat.NoProfile` I still get a context of version 1.0

Comment: What GL context version did you get?

Comment: What video card / driver are you using? Because it'll be the driver issuing that error message.

Comment: To create a GL >=3.2 context (which your shader requires) on mesa, you explicitely have to request a _core profile_. Mesa does not support the compatibility profile at all, and will be limited to GL 3.0 if you don't, and the pasted output of `glxinfo` also confirms exactly that: "core profile version string" vs. "version string".

Comment: Then how can I correctly request such a context? As I said I tried this: `fmt = QGLFormat(QGLFormat.OpenGL_Version_3_3 | QGLFormat.CompatibilityProfile)` and with `CoreProfile` it also doesn't work.